# Does the state object in the store constantly grow the more you use a reducer?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, rxjs

Since the state is immutable, and we return state with the spread operator, does that mean every time we call a reducer, the state is simply going to add data without "purging" or replacing any old data. Is there any purpose in "resetting" or "re-initializing" the state in a reducer as user

Comment: Can you please show us how you are using the spread operator?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new object with the spread operator you are overriding property values.

```
const state = { prop1: 'some value', prop2: 'some value' };

const newState = { ...state, prop2: 'new value' };
```

This create a new object where the value of prop2 is assigned to new value.

In Redux the old state will have no references to the object so it will fall into being marked for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to grow necessarily, why would it?
The reducer is a pure function, it takes the old state and returns the new.
Old state objects that have existed in the heap memory will be dereferenced and garbage collected and replaced by the new.
Re-initialising state in a reducer will not do much in this regard.
The old state object may or may not have been larger, but this isn't gonna cause much of an issue that you would practically care much about.

Comment: Using frequent action dispatches and many reducer functions might grow your store depending on how efficient is your code. There is a possibility that you reach the memory limit.

Comment: @OgnjenMarceta Why would it grow? Haven't run into this problem before.

Comment: Ok, maybe for filling up the initial state with extra character bytes for keeping the state. But you're not supposed to ram a thousand json objects in those arrays. That would be a general JS thing, you would have without Redux if you don't manage it well imo.

Comment: My answer was too generic, I just answered it is possible but that means someone is using it wrongly. To be more precisely I saw that happening with Interns and Juniors. For example, some of them were storing stuff like tables, real-time values multiplied by something, etc. Data that increment overtime requiring more memory until app hits the memory limit.